# CSS does not work with my HTML file. Neither in Chrome, Firefox or VSCode Live Server

Tags: html, css

I can't wrap my head around this one. The two files are in the same folder named "Test".
I already tried and checked these things:

- Tried different paths like href= `"./Test/style.css"` or the complete written path. **Does not work**.
- Checked if they are both encoded in UTF-8. **They are**.
- Used `type="text/css"`. **Doesn't make a difference**.
- Yes, I put it in the head-tag and type `<link href: "./style.css" rel: "stylesheet" type= "text/css"` OR without the "./". **Both don't work.**
- Checked if it's a browser or Live Server problem. **It does not work in either**.
- I tried this super simple code that I believe must be correct to test if I made an error. **Still doesn't work**.

```css
p {
  background-color: green;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel: "stylesheet" type: "text/css" href: "./style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <p>Test Server</p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I can even see that it works apparently when I run it through this site.

- They are in the same directory in the same folder.

[File Path and folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFWS8.png)

- Yes, I changed the backward slash \ to the forward slash / when copy-pasting the path.

I'm really lost and I bet it's something super trivial in the end but I don't see it. I hope someone can figure this out because I can't continue learning this way.
I'm a real beginner and just learned html and css like last week and want to improve on that.

Comment: typo error `<link rel: "stylesheet" type: "text/css" href: "./style.css">` to `<link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

Comment: Typo.  HTML attributes are assigned with a `=`, not a `:`.  So things like `rel: "stylesheet"` should be `rel="stylesheet"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an equals sign instead of a colon in your `link` tag like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```